# Run Functions within Scope of Javascript Source - Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, scope, webpack

Using pure JavaScript in chrome, is it possible to access the scope of a source file? I do not want to use breakpoints, as selenium will not connect with the Chrome debugger running. The source code begins with the following:

```
webpackJsonp([32, 7], [, function(f, l) {
```

And then all of the other functions are defined. Am I able to access within the "`webpackJsonp`"?

All of the functions have commas after them, and they are inside webpackJsonp. For example:

```
webpackJsonp([32, 7], [, function(f, l) {
(function(l) {
    function n(f) {
        console.log('test')
    }, .....
```

EDIT: I would like to be able to access the functions inside of webpackJsonp with the normal console window. This is because `selenium` is only able to access the normal scope (no debugging, breakpoints). So, if possible, I would like to access the functions inside this scope.

Comment: Can you show some more code/context?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Do you want to access these values from the console? Debugger? Other code?  If you could more generally describe the overall problem you are trying to solve, someone may be able to help.

Comment: I have updated the question to make it more specific.